# How to encrypt the connectstring section of web.config in MVC website?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, encryption, web-config, connection-string

i want to encrypt the connectionstring section of my web.config. i have tried to do this by following the below steps:

1. Open Developer Command Prompt for VS2013
2. aspnet_regiis -pef "connectionStrings" -app "/E:\New folder\WebApplication1\WebApplication1"

it is thorwing me error "**a configuration file cannot be created for the requested configuration object. failed**"

I did some google but i am not able to get why i am facing this. i have tried to change the permissions of website folder?

do i need to set the website in IIS?
please help me to solve this issue.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<configuration>
<configProtectedData defaultProvider="SampleProvider">
<providers>
  <add name="SampleProvider" 
    type="System.Configuration.RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider, 
          System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
          PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a,
         processorArchitecture=MSIL"
    keyContainerName="SampleKeys" 
    useMachineContainer="true" />
</providers>
```

add above section into web.config.

1. Open Developer Command Prompt for VS2013
2. change directory to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 using 
   **`cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319`**

   3. run the following command

**`aspnet_regiis -pef "connectionStrings" "E:\New folder\WebApplication2\WebApplication2"`**

It encrypt the connection string. :)